# Please help to identify my error in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

The following query works, but return the primary key multiple times, while there was only one primary key. Please help me to find the error.  Thank you.

````
SELECT INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME, INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.DATA_TYPE, 
   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS.CONSTRAINT_TYPE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE 
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS ON 
   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG =    
       INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG
   AND INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = 
       INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
   AND INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE.CONSTRAINT_NAME = 
       INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS.CONSTRAINT_NAME
RIGHT OUTER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS ON 
   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE.TABLE_NAME = INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME 
   AND INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE.COLUMN_NAME = INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME
   AND INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE.TABLE_CATALOG = 
       INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.TABLE_CATALOG
WHERE (INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME = '#attributes.table#')
ORDER BY INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.ORDINAL_POSITION```
````

Comment: Maybe just doing `SELECT DISTINCT` instead of `SELECT` would fix your problem.  Please learn how to use table aliases; they would make your query much easier to read.

Comment: There might be a scenario of one to many relationship. So if you are getting everything fine as you want, then you should go with @TimBiegeleisen advice. Or may be use other remaining conditions as well to fetch data.

Comment: RIGHT JOIN... Most people find `main table left join optional data` much easier to understand than `optional data right join main table`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add one more condition in first join

```
AND INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE.TABLE_NAME = 
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS.TABLE_NAME
```

Distinct will also work.

Comment: It worked beautifully.  Thank you @md. mahmud hasan

Comment: This is the first time I joined this platform.  Sorry, I don't know where to click to accept the answer. Please advise.

Comment: I figured it out.  Thank you for taking the time to help.